# What if humans were shorter?

Tags: humans, civilization, tools

I was looking outside of the window and got an idea "All tools human use seems to be strangely fit for our size. Buildings, cars, various power tools. All of them are have good size for humans that are 1.5-2m in height." But is that really true?

How would human society, tools, buildings or machines look like if humans were much smaller or shorter. Lets say 1m or 0.5m . Would the buildings or machines be just scaled down or are there any mechanical or technical issues that would need to be handled when fitting them to smaller humans? Or how would such smaller species of humans develop? Would it same as current humans or would there be any differences?

Comment: Humans used to be smaller - go find some old buildings that didn't intentionally have high ceilings (i.e., find houses and pubs, not churches). They will all have really low ceilings.

Comment: We'd all live in hobbit holes.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question to just one question? As written, you're asking us to re-imagine human civilization if everyone were half as tall.

Comment: There are significant differences between asking how would society form in a race of half meter tall humans and asking what problems would half meter tall humans introduce to modern society. Which one would you like to ask?

Comment: @zovits I don't see how my question even implies mixing smaller humans into current society.

Comment: @Green Yes, basically. I'm not seeing any technological or biological problems that would make such species develop differently than us. But I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @Euphoric `Would the buildings or machines be just scaled down`, `technical issues that would need to be handled when fitting them to smaller humans` These for me mean that you wish to take the current state of society and fit it to a humankind suddenly reduced in size. Only in your last two question do you propose that the development could have been completely different.

Comment: @Euphoric Biological problems: Predators. Humans already had desperately fought against tigers, lions, bears, etc. Imagine if the same fights were against foxes and wolves instead. Humankind would not have been able to fight for the role of the dominant species for a long time (invention of gunpowder maybe?), having to resort to escaping and hiding much more often.

Technological: According to the square-cube law, smaller humans would be much stronger, requiring less tools, arguably slowing invention. Larger structures that can't be reduced (bridges) would be much harder to build.

Comment: @zovits: Not necessarily true about the predators.  Despite everything the neighborhood coyotes (no foxes hereabouts) and house cats can do, there are still plenty of squirrels.  Now there might be psychological changes: mini-humans might not think of themselves as the lords of creation, and death from predation would be more common than from cancer, heart disease, &c.

Comment: Look up cube-square (or square cube) law. As you shrink things area goes down by side  squared but volume by side cubed. A say 0.5m tall average is say 3x less tall so 9x less area per height and 27 times less volume per height. And area is 3 x as much per volume. MANY factors are influenced in how the creature works and what the tools and accessories look like. Push a model metal car off a table and it bounces. Push a real car from a scale height and it crumples utterly. Scale the model car up to full size and it is so thick and solid it weighs 20 tons and cannot be powered sensibly. ....

Comment: .... Scale a real car down to model size and it is paper thin and crumples under its own weight. A horse sized ant just scaled up breaks under its own weight. An ant sized elephant scaled down is so heavy for its power it cannot move. Drop a fieldmouse from **ANY** height and it survives (as it's small dimensions make its area so large per mass that its terminal velocity is survivable. ...

Answer (score 2):

If humans were approx half the size they are now, i don't think there would be any technical issues in scaling things down to the new size.  For example if you make a computer half the size, you don't need to make all the small electronic components half the size, you could just rearrange them a bit to fit into a smaller box.

As for "Or how would such smaller species of humans develop? ", i think you need to expand on this question a bit.

Comment: The keyboard on my phone apparently WAS designed for mini-humans :-(

Comment: See my comment above re square-cube law.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon some good points there...

Answer (score 0):

There is a surprisingly exhaustive website called [The Incredible Shrinking Man](http://www.the-incredible-shrinking-man.net/), which, by its own description

> is a speculative design research about the consequences of downsizing the human species to 50 centimeters. It has been a long established trend for people to grow taller. As a direct result we need more energy, more food and more space. But what if we decided to turn this trend around? What if we use our knowledge to shrink mankind?